# charset utf8 is not working in perl code

Tags: mysql, perl

I a newbie in Perl, working on a legacy application. I am missing some special characters like ä,å,ö in my database. previously, Mysql database was in latin1 collation, now changed to UTF-8 default. When I look in database values, these characters are not changed (still getting  some other characters for å,ö,ä). I looked into perl code, I found this encoding and charset seems it is not working.  any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
     use Encode qw/is_utf8 decode/;
     my($q) = CGI->new();
    $q->charset('utf-8');
    $q->header(-charset => 'utf-8', -expires => '-1d')
```

connection to database

```
my($dbh) = DBI->connect($config{'dbDriver'},$config{'dbUser'},$config{'dbPass'}) or die "Kunde inte ansluta till $config{'dataSource'}: " . $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Comment: Please clearify what you doing with result; have use `use utf8` directive or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES 'UTF-8';` on connect to the database.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried after setting 'SET NAMES utf8', it didn't work for me.

Comment: I only really know raw mysql syntax. maybe you could add error messages (if any) to the question?

Answer (score 2):

You should enable `mysql_enable_utf8` already on connection.

```
my($dbh) = DBI->connect($config{'dbDriver'},$config{'dbUser'},$config{'dbPass'}, {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1} ) 
    or die "Kunde inte ansluta till $config{'dataSource'}: " . $DBI::errstr;
```

And you should have your IO set properly, i prefer to use [`utf8::all`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?utf8%3A%3Aall) for it:

```
use utf8::all;
```